# How to avoid number format exception in android while converting string into long?

Tags: java, android

I have string array of data in which I have stored different string values and only two values of the array  I want to convert into `long` but it shows me NumberFormatException below is my code where I have sucked. Moreover Logcat displays values at index 7 and 8.

Method is

```
private void dataSpliter(String data) 
    {
        final String[] myData= data.split("[Â]+");

        Log.e("First Name", ""+myData[0]);
        Log.e("Last Name", ""+myData[1]);
        Log.e("Father", ""+myData[2]);
        Log.e("Gender", ""+myData[3]);
        Log.e("DOB", ""+myData[4]);
        Log.e("Contact", ""+myData[5]);
        Log.e("Address", ""+myData[6]);
        Log.e("Latitude", ""+myData[7]);
        Log.e("Longitude", ""+myData[8]); 

        latitude  = (long)Long.valueOf(myData[7]);
        longitude = (long)Long.valueOf(myData[8]);
}
```

Logcat shows value `myData[7] =34.0012143` and `myData[8] =71.5452969`

Comment: Post the exception with your question. Also no need to cast it to long.

Comment: Show full code and full stacktrace.

Comment: and in addition, post the String values at index 7 and 8...

Comment: @GopalRao That we can see in stacktrace :)

Comment: What is `myData` here? Presumably it's a `String[]`, so it's not clear why you're concatenating it with "" in the logging lines...

Comment: Now plz check my code

Comment: @user3131640 `34.0012143` is a floating point number. How could you convert it to long ? Perhaps are you looking for `double` or `BigDecimal` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the data at `myData[7]` or `myData[8]` isn't containing a `parsable` long value. Either debug or include logs to find the incorrect value and correct it.

Use double instead.

```
double latitude  = Double.valueOf(myData[7]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`34.0012143` and `71.5452969` are not integers and cannot be parsed as longs.

Parse them to double-precision floating point with `Double.valueOf()` or `Double.parseDouble()`.

Some APIs expect to see `long` microdegrees instead of `double` degrees. For that, multiply by  `1e6` and cast to `long`.